# angular: proper to bind view to service data

Tags: angularjs

What is the proper way to bind view to data from a service? **I have seen that $watch is discouraged**.

I have a view that renders items from an array that come from the service.

The service will periodically refresh its data from the server

```
$http({...some params...})
.success(function(data) { 
    cache[key] = data;
});
```

In the view controller the data is exposed :

```
this.items = SomeFactory.cache[key]
```

View is binding :

```
ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items"
```

my understanding is that since `cache[key]` is being assigned to a new array then the view is still binding to the old address and thus not updated.

What is the **proper** way to do this?
It does work if I bind it using a function (eg: `ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items()"` but then how do i modify item? also performance wise i dont know if this is less efficient than binding directly?)

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure it does not update? I've created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wcYonAu5Yh5Zd9hykraf?p=preview) which seems to work that way. Is there something else that might be causing the issue here?

Comment: mmm interesting. i'll try it out more. maybe the two level object is what's causing it.

Comment: No, you're right, I'm dumb. The way you're using it is a bit different from the plunker. I'll write up an answer in a bit about how we deal with similar use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this which I have used quite successfully before:

## Option #1 - bind one way "up"

Assume we have the same factory structure:

```
angular.module('someApp').factory('SomeFactory', function($http) {
  var cache = {};

  $http({...some params...})
    .success(function(data) {
      // ...
      cache[key] = data;
    });

  return {
    cache: cache
  };
});
```

Instead of setting `items` to be the `cache[key]` directly, we can bind to the factory itself. After all, a factory (or a service) is just an object:

```
this.cache = SomeFactory.cache // bind to container which is going to persist
```

Then in the template you just use `ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.cache[key]"` and it will automatically get the latest changes. You can even go the extra step and just bind your service to the scope directly, as `this.SomeFactory = SomeFactory` and then use it in your views as `$ctrl.SomeFactory.cache[key]`. It works well for data structures which are loaded once per app, or for services made specially for a specific controller.

There's a potential problem with this approach depending on how you use it. You mentioned modifying the array but since we override the reference asynchronously, it might be difficult to make sure those changes persist.

## Option #2 - modify the array, not replace it

Another way of solving this is to modify our factory a little bit:

```
angular.module('someApp').factory('SomeFactory', function($http) {
  var cache = {};
  cache[key] = []; // initialise an array which we'll use everywhere

  $http({...some params...})
    .success(function(data) {
      // ...
      cache[key].push.apply(cache[key], data); // essentially a pushAll
      // we could also set cache[key].length = 0 to clear previous data or do something else entirely
    });

  return {
    cache: cache
  };
});
```

As you can see, instead of replacing the reference, we're operating on the same array that the `items` property is referencing. The benefit here is that if we manipulate the array in any way (i.e. add extra items), we have a bit more flexibility about what to do with them once we receive new asynchronous data.

This is in fact similar to the approach ngResource uses - collection query methods return an array which is filled out later on, once the data is actually fetched.

## Option #3 - expose a promise

The final way which I've used before is to just expose a promise for the data:

```
angular.module('someApp').factory('SomeFactory', function($http) {
  var cache = {};

  var whenReady = $http({...some params...})
    .then(function(data) {
      // ...
      cache[key] = data;
      return data;
    });

  return {
    cache: cache,
    whenReady: whenReady
  };
});
```

Then in the controller you just assign it once it resolves:

```
SomeFactory.whenReady.then(items => {
  this.items = items; // or this.items = SomeFactory.cache[key];
});
```

All of these avoid an extra `$watch` but it depends on what's most convenient for your app.

Comment: thanks for a great answer. As for option #2, what is the perf impact of essentially copying all the elements ?

Comment: We're not copying the elements, we're basically calling `cache[key].push` in a loop, so we're not even creating a new array. As far as the performance impact, the best way is to profile - it's most likely going to be insignificant, unless this is something you do very often. I'd say choose whichever solution is most maintainable and then decide after profiling if there's an issue.